# Reuse DTO with different child/nested object

Tags: c#, oop, architecture, modeling

Imagine I have two DTOs that share top level types (`ServerResponseDTO`, `ServerCallDetails`) but the `Items` object has different child object (`ItemsOfTypeA` vs `ItemsOfTypeB`). What would be the best way to reuse defined top level classes without code duplication? - how can I easily instantiate next objects for ItemsOfTypeC, D and so on.

DTO 1:

```
public class ServerResponseDTO
{
  public int CallId { get; set; }
  public ServerCallDetails Details { get; set; }
}    

public class ServerCallDetails
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public Items Items { get; set; }
}

public class Items
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public ItemsOfTypeA Items { get; set; }
}
```

DTO 2:

```
public class ServerResponseDTO
{
  public int CallId { get; set; }
  public ServerCallDetails Details { get; set; }
}

public class ServerCallDetails
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public Items Items { get; set; }
}

public class Items
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public ItemsOfTypeB Items { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Make two classes ItemsOfTypeA and ItemsOfTypeB which inherit the base class Items.

Comment: I'm sorry but advise is not clear. When I make `ItemsOfTypeA` inherit from `ServerResponseDTO` it won't create proper model tree.

Comment: ItemsOfTypeA and ItemsOfTypeB will inherit from, say, ItemsBase class

Comment: When you receive DTO a serialization is performed that takes data and puts into classes.  The following link give code that may be helpful : https://www.sparkhound.com/blog/date-demo-blog?force_isolation=true

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, I don't care about internals of `ItemsOfTypeX`, this class doesn't have to derive from anything. I ask how I can create new type like `ItemsOfTypeC` by reusing parent types. I.e. I can't have two `Items` class as for DTO1 it has `ItemsOfTypeA` when for DTO2 it has `ItemsOfTypeB` so I'm asking how it can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I.e. one of the solution might be to use generic type as Items property so now I can easily create new DTO like: `ServerResponseDTO<ItemOfTypeC>`

```
    public class ServerResponseDTO<T>
    {
      public int CallId { get; set; }
      public ServerCallDetails<T> Details { get; set; }
    }    
    
    public class ServerCallDetails<T>
    {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public Items<T> Items { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Items<T>
    {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public T Items { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> but is there a way without passing T to very bottom object?

No. Imagine you could write the following:

```
public class Items
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public T Items<T> { get; set; }
}
```

What would be the type of the foo variable in the following code?

```
var items = new Items();
var foo = pair.Items;
```

So you have to declare type where your `Items<T>` is used:

```
public class ServerResponseDTO<T>
{
    public int CallId { get; set; }
    public ServerCallDetails<T> Details { get; set; }
}

public class ServerCallDetails<T>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Items<T> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Items<T>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public T FooBar { get; set; }
}
```